# How to get arrangement of two set without repeat by Python?

Tags: python, set

I have already got a method almost can do this:

```
from itertools import product

l = {1,2,3}

print(list(product(l,l)))
```

The output is:

```
[(1, 1), (1, 2), (1, 3), (2, 1), (2, 2), (2, 3), (3, 1), (3, 2), (3, 3)]
```

However, I don't want to the set like (1,1), (2,2), (3,3)

and (2, 3), (3, 2) should only appear once since they are same in set concept.

So the exactly output I want is:

```
[(1, 2), (1, 3), (2, 1), (2, 3)]
```

How can I do this?

Comment: Even `(1, 2)` and `(2, 1)` should not be in the expected output then.

Answer (score 11, accepted):

A simple method [iterools.combinations](https://docs.python.org/3.5/library/itertools.html#itertools.combinations)

```
>>> import itertools
>>> list(itertools.combinations({1,2,3}, 2))
[(1, 2), (1, 3), (2, 3)]
>>>
```

Comment: Thank you for your help! This is extremely helpful! :)

Answer (score 1):

```
You can apply a filter. For e.g.:

>>> from itertools import product
>>> l = {1,2,3}
>>> list(filter(lambda x: [x, None][x[0] == x[1]], list(product(l,l))))
[(1, 2), (1, 3), (2, 1), (2, 3), (3, 1), (3, 2)]
>>>
```